# Common Convention for Denoting "stateful" functions?

Tags: notation

In computer programming it's common to define "functions" (well not really functions) that have a state that persists between calls.  For example, in Python and I want to define a temporal difference and running sum operations:

```
class TemporalDifference:
    def __init__(self, initial=0):
        self.last_x = initial
    def __call__(self, x):
        delta = x-self.last_x
        self.last_x = x 
        return delta 

class RunningSum:
    def __init__(self, initial=0):
        self.sum = initial
    def __call__(self, x):
        self.sum = self.sum + x
        return self.sum

# Which can be used like:
td = TemporalDifference()  # A stateful function
dx = [td(xt) for xt in np.sin(np.linspace(0, 10, 100))]
```

Is there a common convention for expressing this kind of thing mathematically?  I was thinking something like

$$
\Delta(x; x_{last}) := x-x_{last} : x \rightarrow x_{last} \\
\Sigma(x; s) := s+x : s+x \rightarrow s
$$

I'd like to use this notation to conveniently express identities like:

$$
(\Sigma \circ \Delta) (x_t) = x_t \forall t
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  These are common filters that you'll encounter if you study signal processing.  The TemporalDifference is an FIR filter and RunningSum is an IIR filter.

TemporalDifference ->
y[n] = x[n] - x[n - 1]

RunningSum ->
y[n] = x[n] + y[n - 1]

They are both discrete time systems so brackets are used instead of parentheses.  I'd suggest you study the basics of signal processing to get a better idea of how to characterize different systems rather than relying on terms like stateful or stateless (i.e. causal, stable, time invariant, memoryless etc).